# Using Vim with syntastic and SCP

Tags: vim, scp, syntastic

I edit some remote files using vim in combination with scp.  When editing a remote php file using this method syntastic plugin isn't working.

When I type,

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

it says info for file type is php.  So it recognizes the file type but isn't doing the check.  Is this possible using vim with scp?

Comment: How do you combine scp and Vim?

Comment: vim scp://user@123.123.123.123://path/to/file.php

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the manual, see `:help syntastic-netrw`:

> The standard plugin netrw allows Vim to transparently edit files over network and inside archives.  Currently syntastic doesn't support this mode of operation.  It can only check files that can be accessed directly by local checkers, without any translation or conversion.